# SQL Server 2014 : Job Step Runs SSIS from DEV server; Automated way to deploy to production?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I am deploying SSIS packages which are then deployed in DEV (on SQL Server). The packages are executed via job steps using the Integration Services packages job step type (select the type, then select the SSIS server and browse to the package in the catalog)

When this is done, the project and package parameters show up, and we can set certain ones, and others are set via script on the SSIS server so the connection managers IN the package are ok, but FINALLY, my question is:

Does anyone have clever ways to script/deploy the job without having to go change the SERVER: value from, for instance DEVSSIS to PRODSSIS ?

Previously, we were running these packages via PowerShell script that would figure out the local server. We wanted to use the more standard SSIS step so that parameters could be changed if needed in the job step but now it looks like we will have to change the SSIS server by hand.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At a previous shop, we would script out the job, and then at the top we would add a variable, (like `@SSISServerName`) and populate it based on the value of `@@SERVERNAME`   (`WHEN @@SERVERNAME = 'MyDevServer' THEN 'MyDevSSISServer' etc...`)

Then obviously, go through the rest of the script and replace hard-coded SSIS Server Names with the new variable.

It worked back in SQL 2005 for sure.   We could use that job script to deploy the same job to any environment as long as we had accounted for it as a possible `@@SERVERNAME` value.   Dunno if anything has changed in SQL 2014 to prevent this strategy from working.